# Flutter Provider Sorunu

Tags: flutter, provider, riverpod

I have a statefull widget named Hamburger I have a class named _HamburgerState connected to this class. I have an integer value called _count inside my class named HamburgerState. I want the _count value at the time the add to cart button is pressed inside my HamburgerState class to be imported into my StatelessWidget named "CartPage". I heard it was done but I couldn't do it. When I write the code below, I get an error like this. '_HamburgerState' doesn't conform to the bound 'ChangeNotifier?' of the type parameter 'T'.
Try using a type that is or is a subclass of 'ChangeNotifier?'.

```
class Hamburger extends StatefulWidget {
  const Hamburger({super.key});

  @override
  State<Hamburger> createState() => _HamburgerState();
}

class _HamburgerState extends State<Hamburger> {
  int _count = 1;

  void _incrementCount() {...
  void _decrementCount() {...

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color coloricon = Provider.of<iconcolor>(context).coloricon;
    return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
      value: this,
      child: Scaffold(...
    );
  }
}

class AppIcon2 extends ChangeNotifier {...

class CountNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _count;
  int get count => _count;

  set count(int value) {
    _count = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I tried with Provider but I don't know if it works

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I would suggest you to read example of provider. If you still don't understand, I will put a answer here.

Comment: where is example?

Comment: https://flutterbyexample.com/lesson/the-most-basic-example-using-provider